# Not able to scroll in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS. Touchpad settings are missing under Mouse & Touchpad

Tags: scrolling

Image of Mouse & Touchpad settings [image: -]

Edit: I have to bring my pointer to the scroll bar, press left click and then I am able to go up and down the page. I did some research regarding my problem, most of them recommend to disable or enable edge scrolling, two finger scrolling. Terms like "xserver", "xinput" are being used which I am not very much familiar with.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem. 2 fingers scrolling gone.

Comment: After a few reboots and checking the BIOS (didn't change anything), the touchpad and the config of the touchpad are back. I have no explanations. Hardware malfunction?